# How to organize/handle DB related queries?

Tags: symfony

I want to know whats the standard way of structuring DB related operations? Because a structure is not defined in the documentation.

E.g. Have a repoclass and have functions written for getUsername likewise?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly like that.

Your model only contains the entities skeleton. Everything related to querying data for these entities has to be in a Repository.

From the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes):

> In order to isolate, test and reuse these queries, it's a good idea to create a custom repository class for your entity and add methods with your query logic there.